# Почему слово "хрущевка" пишется через Ё?

Tags: орфография

Подскажите, пожалуйста, согласно какому правило в слово "хрущевка" после Щ пишется Ё, а не О, хоть оно и под ударением?
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хрущёвки (дома хрущёвской постройки,  массово сооружавшиеся в СССР во время периода управления страной Н.С. Хрущёва)  получили  в народе его имя и соответствуют написанию имени собственного.

Answer (score 0):

ей-богу даже странно видеть подобный вопрос )) хрущёвка - от фамилии генерального секретаря кпсс ссср Хрущёва Н.С., вот если бы его фамилия была Хрущов, то тогда была бы "хрущовка"

Comment: В диалектах есть слово "хрущ", что значит "жук". Получается, Хрущев и Жуков - этимологически родственные фамилии? Но судя по написанию, ударение должно падать на 1-й слог: ХрУщев. Иначе почему в суф. под ударением после шипящей ё?